# Find the deepest element of a Binary Tree in SML

Tags: binary-tree, sml, smlnj

This is a homework question.

My question is simple: Write a function btree_deepest of type 'a btree -> 'a list that returns the list of the deepest elements of the tree. If the tree is empty, then deepest should return []. If there are multiple elements of the input tree at the same maximal depth, then deepest should return a list containing those deepest elements, ordered according to a preorder traversal. Your function must use the provided btree_reduce function and must not be recursive.

Here is my code:

```
(* Binary tree datatype. *)
datatype 'a btree = Leaf | Node of 'a btree * 'a * 'a btree

(* A reduction function. *)
(* btree_reduce : ('b * 'a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a tree -> 'b) *)
fun btree_reduce f b bt =
   case bt of
   Leaf => b
   | Node (l, x, r) => f (btree_reduce f b l, x, btree_reduce f b r)

(* btree_size : 'a btree -> int *)
fun btree_size bt =
    btree_reduce (fn(x,a,y) => x+a+y) 1 bt

(* btree_height : 'a btree -> int *)
fun btree_height bt =
    btree_reduce (fn(l,n,r) => Int.max(l, r)+1) 0 bt
```

I know that I have to create a function to pass to btree_reduce to build the list of deepest elements and that is where I am faltering.

If I were allowed to use recursion then I would just compare the heights of the left and right node then recurse on whichever branch was higher (or recurse on both if they were the same height) then return the current element when the height is zero and throw these elements into a list.

I think I just need a push in the right direction to get started...

Thanks!

Update:

Here is an attempt at a solution that doesn't compile:

```
fun btree_deepest bt =
let
val (returnMe, height) = btree_reduce (fn((left_ele, left_dep),n,(right_ele, right_dep)) => 
    if left_dep = right_dep 
        then 
            if left_dep = 0 
                then ([n], 1) 
                else ([left_ele::right_ele], left_dep + 1)
        else 
            if left_dep > right_dep
                then (left_ele, left_dep+1) 
                else (right_ele, right_dep+1)
    ) 
    ([], 0) bt
in  
    returnMe
end
```

Comment: As for the compiler error, remove the comma at the very end in `0, bt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the elements of maximum depth, you will need to keep track of two things simultaneously for every subtree visited by `btree_reduce`: The maximum depth of that subtree, and the elements found at that depth. Wrap this information up in some data structure, and you have your type `'b` (according to `btree_reduce`'s signature).

Now, when you need to combine two subtree results in the function you provide to `btree_reduce`, you have three possible cases: "Left" sub-result is "deeper", "less deep", or "of equal depth" to the "right" sub-result. Remember that the sub-result represent the depths and node values of the deepest nodes in each subtree, and think about how to combine them to gain the depth and the values of the deepest nodes for the current tree.

If you need more pointers, I have an implementation of `btree_deepest` ready which I'm just itching to share; I've not posted it yet since you specifically (and honorably) asked for hints, not the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I am still a little confused though. I understand that because SML is functional it will resolve everything to the base case before it starts to run the function `'f` and that my return type `'b` is going to be something like `(r1: list, r2: int)` with r1 being the list of elements and r2 the height. I am still not sure how to specifically compare the "left" r2 to the "right" r2 and then subsequently pass the "correct" r1 up. 

(Which I guess really is the meat of the issue still...)

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Let's say your function `f` is being called with the argument `((left_elements, left_depth), x, (right_elements, right_depth))`. Now, if `left_depth > right_depth`, you keep your `left_elements` for your new result, and increase depth by 1. Vice versa if `left_depth < right_depth`. In case `left_depth = right_depth`, combine your `left_elements` and `right_elements` lists, since the exercise asked to return all elements of the maximum depth.

Comment: Ah, I feel so dumb right now... I've updated my solution attempt above but it is now giving me an error on `if left_dep > right_dep
     then (left_ele, left_dep+1) 
     else (right_ele, right_dep+1)` saying that types of if branches do not agree.

I would just declare a type with left_elements:int list for example but it has to handle both integers and strings interchangeably. 

Am I at least on the right path?

Comment: The issue is with the other `if`, `if left_dep = 0 then ([n], 1) else ([left_ele::right_ele], left_dep + 1)`: `left_ele` and `right_ele` are both lists of node values; therefore, you can't cons (`::`) the one onto the other - you need to append (`@`) one list to the other, and leave out the list brackets (`[`, `]`) like so: `if left_dep = 0 then ([n], 1) else (left_ele@right_ele, left_dep + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Took a look at your code; it looks like there is some confusion based on whether X_ele are single elements or lists, which causes the type error. Try using the "@" operator in your first 'else' branch above:

```
        if left_dep = 0 
            then ([n], 1) 
            else (left_ele @ right_ele, left_dep + 1)
```

Comment: I believe you mean [left_ele]@{right_ele] otherwise it causes compile error because it return to a list.

Comment: No, actually; my code compiles (and passes all of the included tests, if you're in the class I think you are) as posted. FWIW, I have square brackets around 'n', above, but not around left_ele or right_ele anywhere. The idea is for it to always return a list, not a single element and not a list of lists.